# Igros Moshe to R' Shlomo Calerbach

Tags: halacha, history

In [this video](https://youtu.be/CmMkT5xABig) R' Shlomo Calerbach claims there is a teshuva to him in Igros Moshe.

Please help me find it.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/118977/759 ??

Comment: @DoubleAA That link is irrelevant, as it refers to a Teshuva written by RMF ABOUT Carlebach. The OP is asking about a Teshuva allegedly written directly TO Carlebach. At 7:35 Shlomo claims that there is a Teshuva written to him, which is printed in Igros Moshe. Is that a fact, or an embellishment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is found in [Igros Moshe EH 1:32](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=59509&st=&pgnum=69)

[image]

Comment: How to ascertain it was the singer/composer and not his cousin, the almost-sort-of-mashgiach at Chaim Berlin?

Comment: The topic discussed is the one mentioned in the video

Comment: Interesting the teshuva about "the singing rabbi who's doing bad things" is dated only four years and one week later https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=59509&st=&pgnum=245 Much closer than I'd have expected

Comment: He was only 34 when the Teshuva about the singing rabbi was written.

Comment: The details in the Teshuva aren't quite the same as SC says in the video. In the Teshuva, they needed to sign an irrevocable document, that the child that she was carrying would be put up for adoption, immediately after birth. In the video (11:18) SC says that he met the woman at the Kotel, along with the girl, so apparently, she wasn't put up for adoption.

Comment: Further, in the Teshuva, the concern was, that if we don't permit her to marry the first guy (before the requisite 24 months are up), then she might get "sick", or she might go off and marry a secular person. In the video SC says that she threatened to commit suicide within 2 days, if she wasn't allowed to marry him.

Comment: @IsraelReader would not be the first time, nor the last time, that some of the details on the exact case were lost somewhere along the way. (Sometimes how the sender chose to phrase it; sometimes how Rav Moshe understood it; sometimes he's changing details for privacy; sometimes a rabbi may shift and answer the question he'd rather face.)

Comment: @IsraelReader so are you suggesting that there was a similar story with some detail changes that was asked by a different shlomo carelbach?